# Access Python Class Attribute inside externally called method

Tags: python, class, methods, project-structure

In a case like:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init(self, x):
        self.var = x

    def loop(self):
        # [yield params]
        result = self.do_sth(params)

    def do_sth(self, params):
        if self.var is not None:
            bar(params)
        if self.var > 1:
            do_other_bar(params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(2)
```

In my project i have a class consisting of a lot of methods, so I want to move the `do_sth` method outside (e.g. into another module):

```py
# mymodule.py
def do_sth_external(params, var):
    if var is not None:
        bar()
    if var > 1:
        do_other_bar()
```

```py
from mymodule import do_sth_external
class Foo(object):
    def __init(x):
        self.var = x

    def loop():
        # [yield params]
        result = do_sth_external(params, self.var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(2)
```

what other ways are there to break down a huge class?

---

Edit: whatever reason someone thought this question was opinion based. It is asking for best practices...

Comment: If `do_sth()` really needs the `self` then it should be back in the class. If your real name for `do_sth()` is really descriptive and specific, (and it is used by other parts of your code) then it is worth moving to its own module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without agreeing or disagreeing that splitting up a class like this is a good idea, the right approach would be to simply define the method like you always do, and simply assign the function to the appropriate class attribute.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init(self, x):
        self.var = x

    def loop(self):
        # [yield params]
        result = self.do_sth(params)

    def do_sth(self, params):
        if self.var is not None:
            bar(params)
        if self.var > 1:
            do_other_bar(params)
```

becomes

```
# Defined here or in another module, it doesn't matter.
# With the exception of the name the function is bound to,
# nothing else has changed.
def foo_do_sth(self, params):
    if self.var is not None:
        bar(params)
    if self.var > 1:
        do_other_bar(params)


class Foo(object):
    def __init(self, x):
        self.var = x

    def loop(self):
        # [yield params]
        result = self.do_sth(params)

    do_sth = foo_do_sth
```

There's nothing special about a function definition in a `class` statement; the only important thing is that a *name* in the namespace of the `class` statement be assigned an appropriate value. (The metaclass will use all names defined in the `class` statement to add attributes to the resulting class, and an instance method is nothing more than a `function`-valued class attribute.)

---

From time to time, there have been various proposals to allow things like

```
class Foo:
    ...

def Foo.do_sth(self, params):
    ...
```

to facilitate adding methods to a class after it has been created. This is because it's already possible to use assignment statements like

```
def do_sth(self, params):
    ...

Foo.do_sth = do_sth
```

and it's felt that other statements that perform assignments should be able to assign to attributes as well.